# get route name from url in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to get route name from url  in zend framework.
I want to pass URL as parameter to a method that will return route name of the URL.

Using `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName()` I can get the currrent route name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zend doesn't have any direct method for this. But you can get it in this way..

```
$url = 'http://yourproject.com/test/new';

$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);

$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

$router = $frontController->getRouter();

$router->route($request)->getCurrentRouteName();
```

Comment: Please change fontController to frontController ;)